# VS 2017 find and replace ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["stringname"]

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, find

I am trying to find and replace `ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["stringname"]` and `Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["stringname"])` (where "stringname" could be any valid AppSetting name) in all the files in my project with a call to a custom method which wraps this.

There are around 1000 of these entries in the project, trying to avoid doing this manually on each file.

Is there a better way to do this? Gave a few tries with the `Find in all files` with a regex, but with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With regex, you should escape parentheses and Square brackets, since they are special characters in regex.

Comment: But I don't think, you need regex at all, just search for the strings.

Comment: I tried escaping the parantheses with \ that did not seem to work. Not sure exactly what the regex structure should be. I used ConfigurationManager.Appsettings\[(\".*\")\]  I would need to replace ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["SessionTimeout"] to ClassA.Method("SessionTimeout"). I have around 1000 like this.

Comment: Should all 'ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[' be replaced or only for certain 'stringnames'?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to match and replace all with this regex:

```
ConfigurationManager.Appsettings\[([^\])\]
```

The regex search for the string 'ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[', then creates a capturing Group containing the content of the Square brackets.

You then need to replace with:

```
ClassA.Method($1)
```

That will replace with the string, where '`$1`' will be replaced by the matched `Group 1` from the regex (which would be for instance '`"SessionTimeout"`').

Comment: it did not work for me, where you able to test it in VS

Comment: It should Work, are you sure you have checked the 'Regular Expression' checkbox?